# phpseclib shows no error and login fails in HEROKU

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku, composer-php, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to transfer file via SFTP to a server. 
In my local computer the file gets transfered perfectly fine to the server, but on Heroku it does not work at all and login fails each time. I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is the piece of code.

```
 $sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP(getenv('INSTRUM_SERVER'),22222);
        if (!$sftp->login(getenv('INSTRUM_USERNAME'), getenv('INSTRUM_PASSWORD'))) {
            var_dump($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
```

"var_dump" returns an empty array so I am not sure why login fails.

I am using composer for the phpseclib to be loaded from vendor.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the different environment variables to see whether they are correct?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yup, they are all accurate and are visible when I dump them

Comment: @NicoHaase I even removed get env and started using the actual once's there.

Comment: Looks like you posted this at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1240 . FWIW.

Comment: @neubert yes I did, to see if its possible to get an answer from them at least. I will post the right answer here if I get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using phpseclib like this, and it's working fine:

```
private $sftp = NULL;

private function create_sftp_object( $host, $port = 22, $timeout = 10 )
{
    $path = APPPATH . 'libraries/phpseclib';

    set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path );

    include_once( APPPATH . 'Net/SFTP.php');

    return new Net_SFTP( $host, $port, $timeout );
}

public function index()
{
    $this->sftp = create_sftp_object( 
        getenv('INSTRUM_SERVER'), 
        22222, 
        6 
    );

    if( $this->sftp->login( getenv('INSTRUM_USERNAME'), getenv('INSTRUM_PASSWORD') ){
        echo 'Login successful';
    }else{
        echo 'Login not successful';
    }
}
```

It's a little different than your code. As you can see, I have phpseclib in my libraries directory. Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried, doesn't solve the problem unfortunately, worse part, there is no error.

Comment: I don't know anything about Keroku, but my guess is that they might be blocking the port. You should at least contact them and ask.